# Vuejs - Handle key press and Click on table row

Tags: vue.js

How I can capture key press and click on a `tr` element ?

I need to implement a table that can handle a single row selection, or multiple-row selection.

Right now, I tried to bind the key `ctrl`:

```
Vue.directive('on').keyCodes.ctrl = 17;
```

But, if i use `@keyup.ctrl` sure this dont works, because I need to check what key is pressed when the user click on a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The click event includes properties that indicate whether Control, Shift, Alt, or Meta keys were pressed during the click.

```js
new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    controlled: false,
    shifted: false,
    meta: false,
    alted: false
  },
  methods: {
    clicked: function(event) {
      console.debug(event);
      this.controlled = event.ctrlKey;
      this.shifted = event.shiftKey;
      this.meta = event.metaKey;
      this.alted = event.altKey;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<button @click="clicked">Click me!</button>
<div v-if="controlled">Control was pressed</div>
<div v-if="shifted">Shift was pressed</div>
<div v-if="alted">Alt was pressed</div>
<div v-if="meta">Meta was pressed</div>
```